# Improve inefficient nested for loop across conditional mean

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, conditional-statements, processing-efficiency

I have a dataframe `datav2` with the structure:

```
      project_id  hour cap_factor load_area  fuel capacity
17521    1000097 17902   0.753329  CA_PGE_S Solar    21.54
17522    1000097 17901   0.847296  CA_PGE_S Solar    21.54
17523    1001197 17924   0.586530  CA_PGE_S Solar     9.88
17524    2200097 25374   0.000000  CA_PGE_S Solar    44.54
17525    1077597 25414   0.635047  CA_PGE_S Wind     11.33
17526    1000097 19770   -0.39957  CA_PGE_S Solar    21.54
```

The dataframe is 21million rows in length.  I want to loop across every row and, when a given rows `df$cap_factor < 0`, replace that rows `df$cap_factor` with the average of every other cap_factor variable that is of the same load_area, hour, and fuel, and is positive.

Thus far I have been using the following:

```
 datav2$cap_factor2 <-NA

for (i in 1:length(datav2$cap_factor)) {
  if (datav2[i,3] < 0)
    datav2[i,7] <-mean(datav2$cap_factor[datav2$hour == datav2[i,2] & datav2$fuel == datav2[i,5] &
                                           datav2$fuel == datav2[i,4] & datav2$cap_factor >= 0 ])
  else  
    datav2[i,7] <- datav2[i,3]}
```

This is very slow when looping across such a large dataset.  Any suggestions on a technique to improve the efficiency of this process?

Comment: It seems you are calculating the same thing over and over again. How many load_area, hour and fuel groups do you have?

Comment: It also looks like you have a bug: `datav2$fuel == datav2[i,4]`

Comment: Untested dplyr oneliner: `datav2 %>% group_by(load_area, hour, fuel) %>% mutate(mean_pos_cap_factor = mean(cap_factor[cap_factor > 0], cap_factor=ifelse(cap_factor>0, cap_factor, mean_pos_cap_factor))`

Comment: I have 50 load areas, 8760 hours, and 25 fuel groups, all in a melted format

Comment: This dplyr solution seems to be working nicely when coupled with `datav2$cap_factor[datav2$cap_factor < 0] <- datav2$mean_pos_cap_factor[datav2$cap_factor < 0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the means first and then join:

```
structure(list(project_id = c(1000097L, 1000097L, 1001197L, 2200097L, 1077597L, 1000097L), 
               hour = c(17902L, 17901L, 17924L, 25374L, 25414L, 19770L), 
               cap_factor = c(0.753329, 0.847296, 0.58653, 0, 0.635047, -0.39957), 
               load_area = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "CA_PGE_S", class = "factor"), 
               fuel = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Solar", "Wind"), class = "factor"), 
               capacity = c(21.54, 21.54, 9.88, 44.54, 11.33, 21.54)), 
          .Names = c("project_id", "hour", "cap_factor", "load_area", "fuel", "capacity"), 
          class = "data.frame", 
          row.names = c("17521", "17522", "17523", "17524", "17525", "17526"))

library(dplyr)

d %>% subset(cap_factor > 0) %>% 
  group_by(load_area, hour, fuel) %>% 
  summarize(mcap_factor = mean(cap_factor)) %>%
  right_join(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
setDT(datav2)
foo <- function(x) ifelse(x<0, mean(x[x>=0]), x)
datav2[, cap_factor := foo(cap_factor), by=.(load_area, hour, fuel)]
```

testing the code:

```
library("data.table")
datav2 <- fread(header=TRUE, drop="rownr",
'rownr      project_id  hour cap_factor load_area  fuel capacity
17521    1000097 17902   0.753329  CA_PGE_S Solar    21.54
17522    1000097 17901   0.847296  CA_PGE_S Solar    21.54
17523    1001197 17924   0.586530  CA_PGE_S Solar     9.88
17524    2200097 25374   0.000000  CA_PGE_S Solar    44.54
17525    1077597 25414   0.635047  CA_PGE_S Wind     11.33
17526    1000097 19770   -0.39957  CA_PGE_S Solar    21.54')
foo <- function(x) ifelse(x<0, mean(x[x>=0]), x)
datav2[, cap_factor := foo(cap_factor), by=.(load_area, hour, fuel)]
datav2
# project_id  hour cap_factor load_area  fuel capacity
# 1:    1000097 17902   0.753329  CA_PGE_S Solar    21.54
# 2:    1000097 17901   0.847296  CA_PGE_S Solar    21.54
# 3:    1001197 17924   0.586530  CA_PGE_S Solar     9.88
# 4:    2200097 25374   0.000000  CA_PGE_S Solar    44.54
# 5:    1077597 25414   0.635047  CA_PGE_S  Wind    11.33
# 6:    1000097 19770        NaN  CA_PGE_S Solar    21.54
```

showing that you will get a `NaN` for groups with no `cap_factor>=0`.
If you want to test the existence of such a group you can do:

```
datav2[,.(sum(cap_factor>=0), sum(cap_factor<0)),by=.(load_area, hour, fuel)][V1==0 & V2>0]
```

before changing `cap_factor`.